# How to update a user profile property from javascript or workflow in SharePoint 2013 On-Prem?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I have SP 2013 On prem, I am looking to update a user profile property from the client side javascript. Does anyone know a way to do this? I was thinking of client object model, but the article I found about that http://www.vrdmn.com/2015/01/set-user-profile-properties-using-jsom.html says its only for office365/SP online, which I don't have. But then for workflows in 2013, does it have a function that can update user profile properties?

Thanks